# Visual Studio 2010 doesn't deploy App_Theme folder

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, themes, publish

I have a simple web app project in Visual Studio 2010 (converted from 2008 project). For some reason when I publish the app, Visual Studio doesn't copy the App_Theme -folder to the publish destination folder. This will cause the app to fail when deployed to production environment.

App_Theme is considered as "system" folder by VS (shown as grey), which means that I can't manually set it's publish properties.

Can anyone tell me how to get VS to copy App_Theme -folder when deploying?

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, located and deleted TEMP folders with cached data about publish, and then publish gone fine.

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache

%temp%\VWDCache

%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\1.0\Cache
```

Hope this will save time for next people, hitting this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think Visual Studio has a cache file in the root directory where it tracks what files/folders have already been published. If you nuke that file, it should do a full publish again.